# How can I search a value in an array using 2 values as ranges to find the first value?

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, search, textbox

I have 2 arrays. One is called x and has 30 image values. The other is a list of years that correspond to each of the image values in array x. I have 2 textboxes, in each I want to place a year. For example 1919 in one textbox and 1925 in the other box. What I want to happen is have all the images with the corresponding years between 1919-1925 show up in a picture box. I am using visual studios in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Image
{

}

private static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var x = new int[30];
    var images = new Image[30];
    var result = new List<Image>();
    var minYear = 1919;
    var maxYear = 1925;

    for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
    {
        if (x[i] <= maxYear && x[i] >= minYear)
        {
            result.Add(images[i]);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A LINQ version for you to try:

```
public class Solution
{
    private List<Image> x { get; set; } // assuming you initialised this
    private List<int> y { get; set; } // assuming you initialised this

    public List<Image> GetImages(int start, int end)
    {
        return x.Zip(y, (x, y) => new Tuple<int, Image>(y, x)) // merging your two arrays into a list of Tuple<int, Image>
         .Where(i => i.Item1 >= start && i.Item1 <= end) // this is your BETWEEN clause
         .Select(i => i.Item2).ToList(); // returning images
    }
}
```

then call `GetImages(1919, 1925);`

I don't know if this is an option, but I'd suggest you consider merging your two arrays into a list of `Tuple<int, Image>` to begin with, then this merging will not be necessary.